# Analytical evaluation of complex root at real extrema

Tags: complex-analysis

The following is based on my belief/sense: If a Circle radius R is shifted up along

y-axis  to $ (0,h) \; [  h>R $] , then two complex roots exist due to imaginary

intersection of Circle with x-axis (where $ \frac{dy}{dx} =0 )$. The real and imaginary

parts must be functions of $ R , h $ only.

For a real function $ y = f(x) $ the condition to have complex roots is either:

$ y^{'} =0,\; y > 0, \; y^{''} > 0, $ in the neighborhood of a real local minimum, or,

$ y^{'} =0, \; y< 0,\; y^{''} < 0 $ in the neighborhood of a real local minimum.

Is this correct?

If so, please find the complex root of $y = f(x)$ when

$$ y^{'} =0, \; y = A,\; y^{''} = B $$

where  $ A, B $ are positive real numbers, *in terms  A and B* for the  above first case.

We know for the simplest parabolic case $ y = a x^2 + b x + c $ when $ b^2 -4 a c < 0 $ complex roots exist, are given by

$$ \dfrac {-b \pm i \sqrt{ 4 ac -b^2} }{2 a } . $$

May be we can discuss the particular minimum case when  $$ a = 1, b = 2, c =3 $$

$$ y^{'}_{1,2} =0, x_{1,2} = (-1 \pm i \sqrt 2), y_{1} = c- b^2/(4a) = 2, y^{''}_{1} = 2 a = 2. $$

So, for a start express:

$$ \dfrac {-b \pm i \sqrt{ 4 ac -b^2} }{2 a } . $$ in terms of $ A$ and $B$ where $$ A = c- b^2/(4a) , B = 2 a $$

and then proceed towards generalization.

Comment: By "function" do you mean "polynomial"?

Comment: Any function including polynomials.I am looking at single independent variable differential function theory.